# Uniform sampling of 2D path draped on a set of 3D data points

Tags: math, opengl, 3d, geometry, spline

Imagine you have a grid of sample points of a function z = f(x, y) where 1 < x < N and 1 < y < N. The formula is not given, but just the raw data, that could be for example the grey level of an image.

I would like to find, given a point A, whose x and y coordinates are given (and z is known from the data, so A is a vertex of the surface) a number M of points that lie on the circumference of the circle with center in  A and radius R that are a good approximation of a circular "cloth" draped on the imaginary surface described by the data points. Imagine also that the edges of the surface are a triangle mesh.

The biggest constraint in the approximation is that the sum of the length of the edges of the resulting polygon is constantly R * 2 * PI, so that moving the A point across the surface would just change the M points but never the sum of their reciprocal distances. The draping doesn't need to be perfect, it would be nice though to be as close as possible to the surface., or always on one side of the surface, above or below.

Could anybody give me a pointer to something to read about this? Is this a known problem?

I feel that the problem is not completely formulated, I'd already like some help to give a complete description of it.

Comment: I read your question twice, and I still am not sure what you need. Some pictures would help.

Comment: I am takin a plane in one hour, will add some sketches tonight. thx form now

Comment: moved this to [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13561580/find-a-set-of-points-of-a-circle-draped-on-a-3d-height-map)

Comment: Please delete the original question now that you have posted a more complete version