# Find a set of points of a circle draped on a 3D height map

Tags: algorithm, math, 3d, computational-geometry

I have a height map of NxN values.

I would like to find, given a point A (the red dot), whose x and y coordinates are given (and z is known from the data, so A is a vertex of the surface) a set of points that lie on the circumference of the circle with center in  A and radius R that are a good approximation of a circular "cloth" (in grey) draped on the imaginary surface described by the data points.

The sampling, the reciprocal distances between the set of points that I am trying to find,  doesn't need to be uniform, but still I would like to find at least all the points that are an intersection of the edges of the mesh with the circle at distance R from A.

How to find this set of points?

Is this a known problem?

[image: 3d height map with circle draped]
<sub>(source: [keplero.com](http://www.keplero.com/upps/grid.jpg))</sub>

-- edit

The assumption that Jan is using is right: the samples form a regular rectangular or square grid (in the X-Y plane) aligned with [0,0]. But I would like to take the displacement in the Z direction into account to compute the distance. you can see the height map as a terrain, and the algorithm I am looking for as the instructions to give to an explorer that, traveling just on paths of given latitude or longitude, mark the points that are at distance R from A. Walking distance, that is taking into account all the Z displacements done so far. The explorer climbs and go down in the valleys too.

The trivial algorithm for this would be something like this. We know that given R, the maximum displacement on the x and y axis corresponds to a completely flat surface. If there is no slope, the x,y points will all be in the bounding square Ax-R < x < Ax+r and Ay-R

At this point, it would start traveling to the close cells, since if the perimeter enters the edge of one cell of the grid, it also have to exit that cell.

Comment: "circle with center in A and radius R" - please clarify. If it's a circle in the `[X,Y]` space (top-down view), then it boils down to the Pythagorean theorem. If It's a circle in the `[X,Y,Z]` space, then the circle does not lie on the surface. If you mean a sphere, then take the samples from top-down and filter.

Comment: A circle in 3D is not defined by its center and radius. You need its normal (or its tangential plane) as well. Is the circle plane tangential to the surface? If so, you need to describe the interpolation technique as well.

Comment: It looks from the diagram as if the top-down view is meant; then it's trivial.

Comment: OpenGL won't help you there, it's a general maths problem you have.

Comment: Ok, let me clarify. I would like to find the set of points that: 

- lie on the edges of the mesh: so one of their coordinate is an "integer" multiple of the unit of the axes

- have a given distance R from A, "riding" the edges. Imagine that the circle is placed on A and then it sticks to the mesh becoming itself a 3D surface

Comment: So you want to intersect with a sphere, resp. a connected region within that intersection?

Comment: So, you want all points up to a certain distance along the surface?

Comment: @jan exactly... walking distance. Actually my semi proposed algorithm is wrong. I want to find all the points that lie on the edges of the mesh that are exactly at a walking distance of R!

Comment: Computing the walking distance is not exactly trivial. Finding points at a certain distance is harder still.

Comment: @JanDvorak see the walking line, not the sight one, here : http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/map/ref/los2.html
I would like to have the set of points that are both on all those (infinite) paths that start radially from my center, but restrict them to the ones that actually lie on the edges of the grid.

Comment: ... at a given distance.

Comment: I would eventually like to take the draw the spline interpolated curve that passes through the point that I have found. The computation should be quick as the drawing would change with the mouse hovering the surface

Comment: @JanDvorak I think I should cast lines radially from the center and see where they end up... following the triangles of the mesh...

Comment: @AlexDarsonik That does not always produce the shortest path.

Comment: @JanDvorak are you really sure about this? even if the height map is built on a evenly spaced grid?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20125/discussion-between-jan-dvorak-and-alex-darsonik)

Comment: @JanDvorak I thought that the a path is the shortest if I get a straight line unfolding the triangles of the mesh. I have control on those angles so with a limited complexity I could make it...

Comment: @AlexDarsonik I'm in the chat room. Please come.

Comment: Even if you cast a geodesic ("straight line") along the surface, you may not get the shortest path. There may be a shorter geodesic with the same pair of endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

I reckon this is going to be quite difficult to solve in an exact fashion, so I would suggest trying the straightforward approach of simulating the paths that your explorers would take on the surface.

Given your starting point `A` and a travel distance `d`, calculate a circle of points `P` on the XY plane that are `d` from `A`.

For each of the points `p` in `P`, intersect the line segment `A-p` with your grid so that you end up with a sequence of points where the explorer crosses from one grid square to the next, in the order that this would happen if the explorer were travelling from `A`. These points should then be given a z-coordinate by interpolation from your grid data.
You can thus advance through this point sequence and keep track of the distance travelled so far. Eventually the target distance will be reached - adjust `p` to be at this point.

P now contains the perimeter that you're looking for. Adjust the sample fidelity (size of `P`) according to your needs.

Comment: I don't think that the projection on the xy plane of a straight line on a mesh (in the geodesic way) is itself a straight line... no?

Comment: or yes? I am getting really confused. If what you say is correct I will definitely go for it

Comment: you are actually right! the direction on the xy plane actually never change, it's just the vertical component of the vector that does. wow I have spent so much time on this.... for nothing

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify - You have a triangulated surface in 3d and, for a given starting vertex `Vi` in the mesh you would like to find the set of vertices `U` that are reachable via paths along the surface (i.e. geodesics) with length `Li <= R`.

One approach would be to transform this to a graph-based problem:

1. Form the weighted, undirected graph `G(V,E)`, where `V` is the set of vertices in the triangulated surface mesh and `E` is the set of edges in this mesh. The edge weight should be the Euclidean (3d) length of each edge. This graph is a discrete distance map - the distance "along the surface" between each adjacent vertex in the mesh.
2. Run a variant of [Dijkstra's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) algorithm from the starting vertex `Vi`, only expanding paths with length `Li` that satisfy the constraint `Li <= R`. The set of vertices visited `U`, will be those that can be reached by the shortest (geodesic) path with `Li <= R`.

The accuracy of this approach should be related to the resolution of the surface mesh - as long as the surface curvature within each element is not too high the Euclidean edge length should be a good approximation to the actual geodesic distance, if not, the surface mesh should be refined in that area.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, forgive me for the graph, but what I am actually looking for is the set of points that lie on the edges of the triangle mesh (even if they aren't vertices) whose geodesic distance from Vi is exactly R.